# mysql - query to create new table and order it by field name doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I need to create new table and copy data from second table. After it order by field name but this reordering doesn't work. Example: I create a new table and copy data from second table(pizzaName field = a, b, c), after it reorder table by case/when. Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE secondTable (
  pizzaName       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  lowSize         TINYINT     NOT NULL,
  mediumSize      TINYINT     NOT NULL,
  largeSize       TINYINT     NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (pizzaName),
  UNIQUE INDEX pizzaName_UNIQUE (pizzaName ASC) VISIBLE
) AS SELECT * FROM firstTable ORDER BY
    CASE
     WHEN pizzaName = 'c' THEN 1
     WHEN pizzaName = 'a' THEN 2
     WHEN pizzaName = 'b' THEN 3
    END;
```

Comment: there is not a default order by in a sql table (if there is this is casual)  ... if you need  an order  you must ever use a proper order by in the related  select .

Comment: Can u write how to do this ? I am new in mysql

Comment: each time you need  an order by you must explitally add the order by clause  ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split this into two.

The SQL standard doesn't specify the order in which data is stored in the database - it's logically irrelevant (though in practice, clustered indexes do affect the order). There is no way in which you can specify the order in which data is stored other than creating a clustered index but that's not universally supported.

What you *can* do is specify the order in which you retrieve data when querying - that's what the "order by" clause does.

So, step 1 is to create the copy of the table (not sure why you want to do that, but assume it's needed):

```
CREATE TABLE secondTable (
  pizzaName       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  lowSize         TINYINT     NOT NULL,
  mediumSize      TINYINT     NOT NULL,
  largeSize       TINYINT     NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (pizzaName),
  UNIQUE INDEX pizzaName_UNIQUE (pizzaName ASC) VISIBLE
) AS SELECT * FROM firstTable
```

Step 2: retrieve the data from your copy:

```
SELECT * FROM secondTable ORDER BY
    CASE
     WHEN pizzaName = 'c' THEN 1
     WHEN pizzaName = 'a' THEN 2
     WHEN pizzaName = 'b' THEN 3
```